# Ant Design v 5 issue: I get an "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _rcTable.genTable) is not a function"

Tags: antd, rollup

I've updated ant design (I only use antd table) and after using rollup to build my base react components lib and installing it in my app I get this error:

```
base-components.esm.js:65850 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _rcTable.genTable) is not a function
    at base-components.esm.js:65850:1
    at createCommonjsModule (base-components.esm.js:35:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (base-components.esm.js:65840:1)
    at ./node_modules/@biotmed/base-components/base-components.esm.js (base-components.esm.js:111431:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
. . . . .
```

The code causing the error is within ant design that uses rc-table:

```
var _default = (0, _rcTable.genTable)((prev, next) => {
```

I know the table works since testing it with storybook in the lib itself works fine.

"@antd": "5.5.0",
"@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "11.0.2",
"@rollup/plugin-url": "^6.1.0",

This is my first question so maybe go easy on me

I tried simplifying the table and just using only the simple antd example and it didn't help. Using the table causes the issue.

Update: I've noticed that rc-table doesn't exist in antd's node_modules, even though it exists in it's package.json

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is an issue with how I imported the table from antd.

// Wrong:    `import Table from 'antd/lib/table';`

Which is how I imported it before migrated to v5

Importing like this solved the issue:

```
import { Table } from 'antd';
```